# Lining up 6 blocks when 2 can't touch

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Did I do this correctly?:

**edit: I’m told I did this correctly if I distinguish the blue blocks from each other. That’s what I intended**

I have to find how many ways I can line up $6$ colored blocks (blue, blue, green, yellow, red, orange) such that the two blue blocks are **not next to each other**.

I found there to be 5 ways their positions can be next to each other (numbers represent position):
${(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)}$

Now, for each of these possibilities, the pair has $2!$ ways to align in relation to each other while the remaining $4$ blocks have $4!$ ways to line up in relation to each other... so I get

$6! - (5)*(2!)*(4!) = 480$ ways the 2 blue blocks are **not** next to each other.

Thanks for any pointers and help.

Comment: Aren't the two blue blocks *identical* ?

Comment: If the 2 blue blocks aren't identical, your answer is correct. If they're identical, you need to divide by 2.

Comment: @19aksh good catch! Thanks, I intended them to be different I guess.